# Nextjs: eslint rule doesn't affect auto-formatting

Tags: next.js, eslint, eslintrc

I don't like eslint's default no-new-line behavior in else, catch and finally blocks

```
❌
    try {
      // code...
    } catch {
      // more code...
    } finally {
      // even more code...
    }
```

It feels cluttered to me and I want to have a new line between them, like this:

```
✅
    try {
      // code...
    } 
    catch {
      // more code...
    } 
    finally {
      // even more code...
    }
```

The good news is that I already learned that there's an eslint rule for this specific case:

**brace-style: "stroustrup"**

So... I applied it to my .eslintrc file whict looks like this now:

```
{
    "extends": ["next", "next/core-web-vitals"],
    "rules": {
        "brace-style": ["error", "stroustrup"]
    }
}
```

Now the problem is I get errors when there's no new line between else/catch/finally ( great!  ), but still,  every time I save, my code is auto-formatted in that default non-space undesired way ( not so great ... )

How could I have this brace-style rule considered by the autoformatting when I save?